# What are the meanings of ' and beyond' in 'beyond' in 'Building forms and beyond'?

Tags: american-english

Here is the context:

> This chapter covers
>
> Generating HTML with UI component tags
>
> Building forms and beyond
>
> Snazzing it up with templates and themes
>
> Surveying the components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means the author wanted to talk about building forms plus some other stuff that is related, but is either (a) less important and so shouldn't be mentioned in the sub-heading, or (b) involves several different topics that cannot easily be summarized in one or two words.

Answer (score 0):

> Building forms and beyond

means "Building forms and more things you can do related to building forms".

Answer (score 0):

In this context it means "to go further than the subject matter or title suggests".

> Building a web form requires that you
>   do ABC, but having learnt those skills
>   you could employ them to do XYZ which
>   has nothing to do with building web
>   forms.